# docusaurus won't pick up my translated markdown files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, docusaurus

My docusaurus project structure:

```
website
|--docs
|----homepage.md
|--i18n/de/docusaurus-plugin-content-docs/current
|----homepage.md
```

When I use the language switch I get directed to `http://localhost:3000/website/de/docs/homepage/` but I get a "Page not found" error the page. Also when I click on german in the language switch again it will just append another "de" to the url, so the url will then look like `.../website/de/de/docs/...`

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a docusaurus issue?